# Getting values from generated select list

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I created a function to generate a table with a select list. The function works, but I am having a problem getting the values from the select list.

I set the id of the select-list and an onchange function like this:

```
  var selectList = document.createElement("select");
  selectList.setAttribute("id", "numSelect");     
  selectList.setAttribute("onchange", getVal());
```

However, the function is not finding the id, and hence is not able to get the values:

```
  function getVal() {
  var sect = document.getElementById("numSelect");
  var opt = sect.options[sect.selectedIndex].value;
  console.log(opt);
  //var totalSect += opt;
  //console.log(totalSect);
  };
```

I know I am close, but no cigars are in sight. The "getContent" function returns "null" for the values in the select boxes.

I would like to be able to
a) Update the total section count ("totalSect") as the numbers are selected, and 
b) Be able to read the completed table and save it to an array.

I know jQuery makes this easier, and sooner or later I will break down and learn it, but does anyone have a pure JavaScript answer?

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/1mnxna3p/5/

Comment: The way that is written, you are setting the onchange attribute to the value that the getVal() function returns. Are you trying to set an event listener on the select box? You would want to use selectList.addEventListener('change', getVal);

Comment: That clears up getVal blocking the select list creation, but it does not seem to be returning any values in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this, let me know if that works..

```
    function getVal(ob) {
  var opt = ob.options[ob.selectedIndex].value;
  console.log(opt);
  //var totalSect += opt;
  //console.log(totalSect);
};
```

and this

```
  var selectList = document.createElement("select");
  selectList.setAttribute("id", "numSelect");     
  selectList.setAttribute("onchange", "getVal(this)");
```

refer https://jsfiddle.net/1mnxna3p/10/

Comment: Since you are using select multiple times its better to remove ID attribute. The above fix will work without attribute also.

Comment: Nice! That seems to work well. Could you just explain why it would be a good idea to get rid of the ID attribute, and would that help with the getContent function returning "undefined"?

Comment: ID's are meant to be used only once in a page. If we use the same ID multiple times sometimes it may misbehave and for getting values in getContent, updated here https://jsfiddle.net/1mnxna3p/13/